# "if" does not trigger when condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have the following block of code:

```
idatual=txt2['pvSystems'][x]['pvSystemId']
nomedocliente = txt2['pvSystems'][x]['name']
nomesclientes = pd.read_excel(file_loc, sheet_name="MONITORAMENTO", index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "B")
y=0
print("name of the client: " + str(nomedocliente))
while y < len(nomesclientes):
    print("name of the client on the sheets: " + nomesclientes.iloc[y][0])
    if nomedocliente == nomesclientes.iloc[y][0]:
```

So, a few things worth noticing:

- "nomedocliente",the first element on the comparison, is taken from a response originated by a request.
- The idea is to compare "nomedocliente" to the values of a column from an Excel sheet, if the value is equal, we trigger an action.
- Both values are strings.
- The code works for the most values, but it doesn't work on very specific cases, like:

Case 1:

```
    name of the client: Pice e Cia
    name of the client on the sheets: Pice e Cia
```

Case 2:

```
    name of the client: Iolanda Saraiva Irecê
    name of the client on the sheets: Iolanda Saraiva Irecê
```

- Problem cases don't have a pattern on them.
- I've assured that those strings are equal, since they trigger if statements on other cases.

Any ideas ?

EDIT:

I've followed the solution that it was linked to this question and it did NOT help. I've changed the code to normalize the strings:

Older line:

```
if nomedocliente == nomesclientes.iloc[y][0]:
```

New Line:

```
 if (unicodedata.normalize('NFC',str(nomedocliente)) == unicodedata.normalize('NFC',str(nomesclientes.iloc[y][0]))):
```

The problem was not solved.

Comment: The problem occurs because strings that appear identical can sometimes have different actual Unicode code points in them, thanks to how Unicode works. See the linked duplicate for more information.

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't these strings never trigger a if statement ? When I copy and paste those strings on another if statement they work. They specifically don't work inside this loop

Comment: Have you tried trimming whitespaces? Have you tried to compare bytes of your problem cases? `str.encode(my_str)`

Comment: Hello ! I've solved this question befor it got reopened. The trimm + the normalizing solved the problem for me.